# What is this JSON-like data format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

The Chrome Web Store returns responses with Content-Type: application/json like

```
)]}'

[[["versionresponse","20181009"]
,["getitemsresponse",[]
,null,[]
,"featured:0@116161:7:false,mcol#chrome_themes:0@116162:11:true,mcol#zodiac_animals_theme:0@116163:11:true,mcol#dark_themes:0@116164:11:true",null,null,[["featured",[]
,"#@","0@116161",0]
,["mcol#chrome_themes",[["aghfnjkcakhmadgdomlmlhhaocbkloab","Just Black","The Chrome team","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/vSHe832CyO0J6LOpXO-zcBuy6OILoYL1_sCGfsNbKyCGp7ziSUje-AC5BxCPL8jkJCkrjnxqUA\u003dw26-h26-e365","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HeIhD939ekiN8e39w7rD0kAva5hw_bzWcWj7BIn4QQf_MGbhnwUQVhCaBcYXxr9r6yb3eKuX\u003dw220-h140-e365",null,"Just Black: when you're feeling extra moody",[]
,1,"themes","Themes","http://chrome.google.com/extensions/permalink?id\u003daghfnjkcakhmadgdomlmlhhaocbkloab",4.566780821917808,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,584,"477,641",null,"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/vSHe832CyO0J6LOpXO-zcBuy6OILoYL1_sCGfsNbKyCGp7ziSUje-AC5BxCPL8jkJCkrjnxqUA\u003dw128-h128-e365",0,0,"theme/free/aghfnjkcakhmadgdomlmlhhaocbkloab/just_black",null,"Free",1,null,null,null,null,null,"https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/just-black/aghfnjkcakhmadgdomlmlhhaocbkloab",null,null,null,null,null,[]
,null,19,"/webstore/detail/just-black/aghfnjkcakhmadgdomlmlhhaocbkloab?hl\u003den-US\u0026gl\u003dUS",null,null,null,null,0,null,0,0,null,1,0,null,0,1,"just-black",null,null,0,"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HeIhD939ekiN8e39w7rD0kAva5hw_bzWcWj7BIn4QQf_MGbhnwUQVhCaBcYXxr9r6yb3eKuX\u003dw141-h90-e365",0,0,[]
,null,0,0,[]
,null,null,"Free","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HeIhD939ekiN8e39w7rD0kAva5hw_bzWcWj7BIn4QQf_MGbhnwUQVhCaBcYXxr9r6yb3eKuX\u003dw440-h280-e365",null,0,null,null,null,"",null,"Published",1]
,["cmhmcmgkegfffbbfobhjpdbimgmoohap","Slate","The Chrome team","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ZxOvvku7SHr_7ygXAj4WbXggqfta7M6CdYLmQ_lYaXZACqKTRZcGH-pVYWjprAKzonDIbBdQ_w\u003dw26-h26-e365","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/T5u4FelQiaP4uU8L4pPTILFDhVkbqU8lPTo1xHgeDGz_6gtbhOPfgCXEr5e0pKMJ21pXKNNuHw\u003dw220-h140-e365",null,"Slate is cool and composed",[]
,1,"themes","Themes","http://chrome.google.com/extensions/permalink?id\u003dcmhmcmgkegfffbbfobhjpdbimgmoohap",4.7650273224043715,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,183,"107,384",null,"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ZxOvvku7SHr_7ygXAj4WbXggqfta7M6CdYLmQ_lYaXZACqKTRZcGH-pVYWjprAKzonDIbBdQ_w\u003dw128-h128-e365",0,0,"theme/free/cmhmcmgkegfffbbfobhjpdbimgmoohap/slate",null,"Free",1,null,null,null,null,null,"https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/slate/cmhmcmgkegfffbbfobhjpdbimgmoohap",null,null,null,null,null,[]
,null,19,"/webstore/detail/slate/cmhmcmgkegfffbbfobhjpdbimgmoohap?hl\u003den-US\u0026gl\u003dUS",null,null,null,null,0,null,0,0,null,1,0,null,0,1,"slate",null,null,0,"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/T5u4FelQiaP4uU8L4pPTILFDhVkbqU8lPTo1xHgeDGz_6gtbhOPfgCXEr5e0pKMJ21pXKNNuHw\u003dw141-h90-e365",0,0,[]
,null,0,0,[]
,null,null,"Free","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/T5u4FelQiaP4uU8L4pPTILFDhVkbqU8lPTo1xHgeDGz_6gtbhOPfgCXEr5e0pKMJ21pXKNNuHw\u003dw440-h280-e365",null,0,null,null,null,"",null,"Published",1]
,["mhhlgkfginnlendpfkhcmldikeepoefa","Black \u0026 White","The Chrome team","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2quMKl7oBjBPFbxn65qKAmDol0qb-EZ-9CBL_RgjEeAAXC5Y5YoM1K-9diwHrbI8prQ4T3WTPA\u003dw26-h26-e365","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uB1nO6bTEvYDtoOSpJWeX59I-n-hVsZB-CTr6RWBCLgjQ8nRmkfLnMu5RoPFrHi53lUcvmExHZk\u003dw220-h140-e365",null,"Black \u0026 White: a timeless combination",[]
,1,"themes","Themes","http://chrome.google.com/extensions/permalink?id\u003dmhhlgkfginnlendpfkhcmldikeepoefa",4.541666666666667,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,120,"58,473",null,"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2quMKl7oBjBPFbxn65qKAmDol0qb-EZ-9CBL_RgjEeAAXC5Y5YoM1K-9diwHrbI8prQ4T3WTPA\u003dw128-h128-e365",0,0,"theme/free/mhhlgkfginnlendpfkhcmldikeepoefa/black_._white",null,"Free",1,null,null,null,null,null,"https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/black-white/mhhlgkfginnlendpfkhcmldikeepoefa",null,null,null,null,null,[]
,null,19,"/webstore/detail/black-white/mhhlgkfginnlendpfkhcmldikeepoefa?hl\u003den-US\u0026gl\u003dUS",null,null,null,null,0,null,0,0,null,1,0,null,0,1,"black-white",null,null,0,"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uB1nO6bTEvYDtoOSpJWeX59I-n-hVsZB-CTr6RWBCLgjQ8nRmkfLnMu5RoPFrHi53lUcvmExHZk\u003dw141-h90-e365",0,0,[]
,null,0,0,[]
,null,null,"Free","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uB1nO6bTEvYDtoOSpJWeX59I-n-hVsZB-CTr6RWBCLgjQ8nRmkfLnMu5RoPFrHi53lUcvmExHZk\u003dw440-h280-e365",null,0,null,null,null,"",null,"Published",1]
,["gbbacdmgjdfajabgglpjifcedoajdimg","Oceanic","The Chrome team","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TaBZo0yvW2VetcYP_51RWb7UxavWXlGL1g9lLw0KaPSjs9d7lOUgKVVQ2CEzWm9vF613s9aMldY\u003dw26-h26-e365","https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KKTIP20ruW9fP8AssGmA_lYV29ygWj2zwFOfSxaRWw0h01Wcqp441X8Q8UrVJIhOKKRLKdWlWKU\u003dw220-h140-e365",null,"Oceanic: as deep and mysterious as the sea",[]
,1,"themes","Themes","http
...
```

The prefix is probably a security measure, but the nested JSON array format is interesting to me.

Is there is a known named technique for nested JSON arrays (i.e. no objects) with an external useable schema definition?

Comment: Security SE covers it pretty well: [How does including a magic prefix to a JSON response work to prevent XSSI attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/110539/43940)

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to say, here. As far as I can see, it's not "JSON-like"; other than the security line you already identified,, whichumably gets stripped off before parsing, it appears to just be normal JSON. Why they've built it all as arrays, I don't know; presumably it just works nicely for whatever function is going to process it. I guess not having the string keys saves some space when transmitting it.

Comment: @IMSoP, I'm pretty sure the arrays is for performance/size. They likely have an external schema that associates each index with something semantically meaningful.

Comment: Sounds like you've got it all pretty much figured out then, so I'm not sure what the question is, unless it's "does anyone have the source code for the application that processes these responses". I'm not sure what you mean by "external schema", though - the "schema" for this could be as simple as a bunch of functions which take bits of the data as ordered arguments.